# Getting error in installing tf2onnx on pip

Tags: tensorflow, pip, tf2onnx

I am trying to convert my .pb model to .onnx and for that I am installing tf2onnx using pip. However, doing that I keep getting following error

```
C:\Users\HC>pip install -U tf2onnx
Collecting tf2onnx
  Using cached tf2onnx-1.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (435 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers~=1.12
  Using cached flatbuffers-1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.1 in c:\users\hc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from tf2onnx) (1.22.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\hc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from tf2onnx) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\hc\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from tf2onnx) (1.16.0)
Collecting onnx>=1.4.1
  Using cached onnx-1.10.2.tar.gz (9.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qij5_ixj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 162, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(
        File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qij5_ixj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 143, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qij5_ixj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\HC\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qij5_ixj\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 86, in <module>
          assert CMAKE, 'Could not find "cmake" executable!'
      AssertionError: Could not find "cmake" executable!
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Please can anyone guide how to tackle this

Answer (score 2):

`AssertionError: Could not find "cmake" executable!` indicates that pip couldn't find cmake. You should install it (https://cmake.org/download/) or add it to your PATH.

Comment: I installed cmake now im getting error at end note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Failed to build onnx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for onnx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: If you include more of the error as you did in your original question, I’d be able to help. As it stands, it’s hard to tell why the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, the problem is that `cmake` is not installed. However, you can avoid this problem entirely by using Python 3.9 or 3.8. `pip` can install pre-compiled `onnx` for those python versions.

See https://pypi.org/project/onnx/#files

Comment: my python version is 3.10 installed already, now what? and I am unable to instal onnx too saying note: "This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for onnx
Failed to build onnx
ERROR: Could not build wheels for onnx, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Comment: I am saying that 3.10 is too new for onnx. If you downgrade to 3.9, you will not have to build from source. Your errors arise from attempting to build from source.